# Symfony : Upgrading from 2.8 to 3

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I got errors when I tried to upgrade symfony from 2.8 to 3 :

- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 3.0.x-dev
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.8
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.7
- webfactory/exceptions-bundle 4.3.0 requires symfony/twig-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.13, 2.2.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev,
  2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev], symfony/twig-bundle[2.2.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev,
  2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9,
  v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15,
  v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
  v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28,
  v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34,
  v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40,
  v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0,
  v2.4.0-BETA1, v2.4.0-BETA2, v2.4.0-RC1, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2,
  v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0,
  v2.5.0-BETA1, v2.5.0-BETA2, v2.5.0-RC1, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11,
  v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8,
  v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.0-BETA1, v2.6.0-BETA2, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11,
  v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7,
  v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10,
  v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17,
  v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6,
  v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10,
  v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6,
  v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2,
  v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9].
- Installation request for webfactory/exceptions-bundle ^4.3 -> satisfiable by webfactory/exceptions-bundle[4.3.0].

This is my composer.json :

```
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.26",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
        "adesigns/calendar-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle" : "1.5.4",
        "liip/imagine-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "jordillonch/crud-generator" : "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "kms/froala-editor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "webfactory/exceptions-bundle" : "^4.3",
        "lexik/translation-bundle": "^4.0",
        "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "dev-master",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.0",
        "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "^2.1",
        "besimple/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "~1.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "unifik/database-config-bundle": "dev-master",
        "beelab/recaptcha2-bundle": "~1.2",
        "dario_swain/ds-recaptcha-bundle": "dev-master",
        "avocode/form-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "gos/web-socket-bundle": "~1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
        "umpirsky/symfony-upgrade-fixer": "^0.1.5"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
beelab/recaptcha2-bundle v0.1.3 requires symfony/symfony ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev].
```

This means, that the recaptcha2-bundle doesn't allow a Symfony 3 installation. If you want to upgrade to Symfony 3 then you have to check, if that bundle is available in newer version or you have to remove that bundle.

Comment: this bundle is available in newer version, but when I change it in composer.json to "~1.2", i get this erreur (The requested package beelab/recaptcha2-bundle (locked at v0.1.3, required as ~1.2) is satisfiable by beelab/recaptcha2-bundle[v0.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.)